# Closing and opening navigationbar with same button (2 different funcionts)

Tags: javascript

My navigation bar uses JavaScript to open and close but requier two seperate functions to either open or close.

```
openNav() - open
closeNav() - close
```

the function of the navigation bar is taken from W3-schools http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

What is the easiest way to open and close using "same" button?
Could i change the `onlick=""` value each time the button is pressed or should i use two buttons and hide each other when one is pressed?

script:

```
<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "140px";
    document.getElementById("tabs").style.width = "70%";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.borderRight = "2px solid #0bb1ff";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("tabs").style.width = "80%";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.border = "0";
}
</script>
```

button :

```
<div class="drop-menu" id="menu" onclick="openNav();"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a toggleNav function that checks current state of nav and does either option a of opening or option b of closing

```
var navBarOpen = true;
function toggleNav() {
 if (navBarOpen) {
   // close it 
   navBarOpen = !navBarOpen;
 else { 
  // open it 
  navBarOpen = !navBarOpen;
 }
```

that should work just fine just put the code in the appropriate places